# How to merge changed Git repository with my local?

Tags: git, github

I am working with my friend in same repository. He changed the code and push in repository. And I have changed as well. So when I want to puhs my code, it throws error. I want to pull, another error message apepars that says me repository changed. I could not merge it. Should I commit my local before pull?

Comment: yes, you should commit. It's always best to commit your local changes before you take pull. Cause it's easier to abort the conflicts when you want to go back from fixing conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following.

1. `git status` - always git status , to see your changes
2. `git add .` - add the changes
3. `git commit -m "Your commit message"` - commit
4. `git pull origin YourBranch` - pull the code he pushed
5. Now the merge will occur. Resolve conflict and then commit the resolved and
6. `git push origin YourBranch`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git stash` command. So you save your current changes without commit and return it after do what you wanted. This is a more convenient way if you need to quickly do something, but not you ready to do commit.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash